# How to use accounts-ui with Blade?

Tags: meteor, node-blade

[Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui) say to just add `{{loginButtons}}` to your template. If I'm not mistaken, this is essentailly `|= loginButtons` in Blade.  However, I'm getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: loginButtons is not defined

I have the `accounts-ui` package,s o I'm not sure why it's erroring.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

---

Added this to my Blade template:

```
- console.log(Template)
```

And I can see all the login stuff in there, so... its definitely there. I just don't know how to access it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, this works:

```
!= Template._loginButtons()
```

I'm not super keen on using it though as it starts with an underscore (probably subject to change).